# Is it possible to write a where case when @filter=1 ....?

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, case

Working with

- SQL server 2005
- procedures
- parameters

I have a normal query:

```
select column1, column2
from table1
where column3 in ( select columnb from table2 )
```

and now I have a filter for example an int

```
declare @filtertype int /*@filtertype=1 then column3,@filtertype=2 then column2*/ 
set @filtertype int
```

i nedd somethings as this

```
select column1, column2
from table1
where
   case when @filtertype=1 then (column3 in (select columnb from table2))
   else (column2 in (select columnb from table2))
```

if you see it, you could see unique change is column3 for column2

I do not want to duplicate my large query like this:

```
if(@filtertype=1)
begin
   first query
end
else
   other query
begin
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
   select column1, column2 
    from table1 
    where 
    (@filtertype=1 AND (column3 in (select columnb from table2)))
    OR
    (@filtertype=2 AND (column2 in (select columnb from table2)))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
...
from ...
where (@filtertype=1 and column3 in (select ... from table2))
or (@filtertype<>1 and column2 in (select ... from table2))
```